# How can I embed a CefSharp webbrowser control in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, cefsharp

I need the dll files to be included in the form controls so as to insert the web browser control in the form itself ... how can I do? This time I really need help because I'm going crazy; if you help me, do me a big favor!

Comment: What exactly are you having a problem with? What have you tried so far, please edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

When you ad reference, add the browser control via code (as you can't do it via designer).

For example:

```
Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
        Dim CefSharp_Settings As New CefSettings With {
       .ResourcesDirPath = Application.StartupPath,
       .LocalesDirPath = Application.StartupPath & "\locales",
       .CachePath = Application.StartupPath & "\CefSharp Cache"
        }
       CefSharp_Settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("persist_session_cookies", "1")
       CefSharp.Cef.Initialize(CefSharp_Settings)
       chromeBrowser = New ChromiumWebBrowser("www.google.com") With {
       .Dock = DockStyle.Fill
       }
       Me.Controls.Add(chromeBrowser)
End Sub
```

Comment: No, so I wrote the question wrongly: I don't know how to import it

Comment: Tools > NuGet PM > Browser > Install